# msdeploy not copying files starting with a dot

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, msdeploy

Some of the files for the website I'm moving start with a dot, IE .htaccess or .hiddenFolder or anything similar to that.  I'm trying to move these sites from IIS6 to IIS7 (there's hundreds of separate sites), but it won't copy these files and the program fails.  Does anyone know a way around this?

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy>msdeploy -verb:sync -source:metakey=lm -dest:archivedir=L:\ancomm2,encryptPassword=pass > msdeployarchive.log

Error: Attempt to perform an unauthorized operation on file 'L:\ancomm2\Content\C_C\Inetpub\vhosts\Servers\20937\localuser\ajmoore\.Security'.
Error: Access to the path is denied.
Error count: 1.
```

Comment: the error you posted isn't for a file that starts with a dot. Can you post an error that matches your problem description please?

Comment: Sorry.  It did not format properly and the backslash was hidden

Comment: sorry to comment you to death instead of answer your question, but could you turn on the `-verbose` flag for msdeploy and see if it includes any further useful information?

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions on both the IIS and make sure that Shares are enable for Drive and stop any firewall if running.